# SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM in Windows store application

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

I am using VS 2013 for developing my Windows Store app using C#.

Here I am invoking a service call to upload image as byte array. See below the codes:

```
           public async void SanUploadImage(byte[] data)
            {
                FileUploadDetailsRequest objFileUploadDetailsRequest = new FileUploadDetailsRequest();
                DocumentUploadServiceClient objDocumentUploadServiceClient = new DocumentUploadServiceClient();
                string loginID = "259021";
                objFileUploadDetailsRequest.AppId = 116; // ID card app id
                objFileUploadDetailsRequest.AppTemplateId = "ERREY34654";
                objFileUploadDetailsRequest.FileName = "MyFile.jpg";
                objFileUploadDetailsRequest.IncomingFile = data;
                objFileUploadDetailsRequest.CreatedBy = loginID;
                objFileUploadDetailsRequest.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                objFileUploadDetailsRequest.AssociateId = 394346;

                // Service method call           
 var objMFileuploadResponse = await          objDocumentUploadServiceClient.UploadFile_WithResponseAsync(objFileUploadDetailsRequest);
            }
```

While executing my service call, i am getting the below error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code    
Additional information: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.


at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass5`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SANTesting.MainPage.<SanUploadImage>d__7.MoveNext()
```

The above uploading method working fine while executing from normal windows/asp .net applications.

Kindly help

Comment: Have you set client and server in manifest capabilities?

Comment: Yes. Already checked those features. I am able to call other methods on same service

Comment: What's the definition of `FileUploadDetailsRequest` on the server side? Is there a mismatch in field names, or a `DateTime` field that's not being set on your end? The error simply means that, most probably, the code is trying to pass an unassigned `DateTime` to the database (meaning it has the default value of 0001-01-01, which SQL Server doesn't support).

Comment: The same invocation code is working fine in normal C# windows application